# How to delete U2 album from iPod Touch

Tags: ipod-touch

The free U2 album was downloaded to my iPod Touch. It does not show up in my iTunes library on the computer. I do not want this album. How do I now delete the songs from my iPod Touch?

Answer (score 2):

You just have to go to the following link, and press the "Delete album" button:

https://buy.itunes.apple.com/WebObjects/MZFinance.woa/wa/offerOptOut

Edit: More info can be found on [this official link](http://support.apple.com/en-us/ht6439) from Apple.

Comment: Hello friend. If that answer worked for you, please select it as the correct one. It will give me some usefull reputation so I could hep some other people too. Thanks.